# Gradle- Eclipse and IDEA plugin in same script?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, gradle

I'm trying to figure out how Gradle applies IDE plugins. If I wanted a `build.gradle` script that accommodated both Eclipse and IDEA, can I declare both plugins in the script? Will it try to create the metadata for both? Or is the IDE Gradle implementation start enough to choose the correct one?

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
```

I just want to make sure that when I put any project source files in a GIT repository with the `build.gradle` script, the import and build experience will be fine for those IDEs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the eclipse plugin simply adds eclipse tasks to the build allowing to generate an eclipse project from the gradle project.

Applying the idea plugin simply adds idea tasks to the build allowing to generate an IDEA project from the gradle project.

I don't see any reason why you couldn't do both.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the plugins to your `build.gradle` file doesn't do anything until you run one or more of the tasks that these plugins introduce. It wont create any metadata for either IDE until you run the specific tasks.

For a list of tasks that each plugin adds, see these links:

ref:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html
http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html